# Coord ArrayLists should both have the same size

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

In a bomberman-like puzzle game, those lines are made to identify the best spot to drop a bomb(between two crates). It's a 13*11 grid.

When I check the size of the 2 objects, the one stocking the X is far bigger than the other one. 
They are supposed to have both the same size each coord X coming with his Y.

Being that first best moves are on the same Y axis, I suspect the 2nd arraylist not to create a new room to store them (but it is ArrayList and not Set so ?).

```
ArrayList<Integer> bestSpotX=new ArrayList<Integer>();    
ArrayList<Integer> bestSpotY=new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ...
for (int line=0, col=0;line<11 && col<13;line++, col++) {    
    if ((map[line].charAt(col)=='0')&&(map[line+2].charAt(col)=='0')) {
    bestSpotX.add(col);
    bestSpotY.add(line+1);
    }    
}
```

Is my iteration false, or is it the way I'm adding the coord values ?

Comment: "When I check the size of the 2 objects, the one stocking the X is far bigger than the other one." Your question show no code in which you check this assertion. From the presented code, there are plenty of chances where the things may go wrong before or after the cycle.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, Adrian. In fact, I'm sure of the rest of the code, cause it works nice when iterated on a simple array, but It obliges me to "hardcode" the length (each game, the crates position change and so the good combinations do). That's why I chose an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why:

```
ArrayList<Integer> bestSpotX=new ArrayList<Integer>();    
ArrayList<Integer> bestSpotY=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and not:

```
class LineColLocation {
  protected int line, col;

// constructors, setters and getters
}

ArrayList<LineColLocation> bestSpots=new ArrayList<LineColLocation>();    


int bestSpotLine=...; // ... whatever logic to ...
int bestSpotCol=...;  // determine a *best spot*

LineColLocation bestSpot=new LineColLocation(bestSpotLine, bestSpotCol);
bestSpots.add(bestSpot);
```

This way you won't be able to accidentally mess with the **implicit requirement* of `same number of X and Y in two different lists` - you just materialize this constraint (make it explicit), make unnecessary the verification of this constraint and you'll be sure every time you can't screw the things.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a newbie in Java, I always coded in C and need to think "Object" !